# Remove closed question

Tags: support, closed-questions

I want to delete my closed question because it was kept too general (maybe I better ask several questions to achieve explicit answers). In order to clean up, it would make sense in my eyes to remove the question, but I can not delete it at the moment.

> To allow for possible reopening, you may delete in 11 hours

I am aware that deleting a topic has to be thought very carefully as explained in [Closing/Removing your own questions - standard process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121091/closing-removing-your-own-questions-standard-process)

What is exactly happening while a question got closed? I do not find further details on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer as I'm told:

The selected elite members of the society put a drop of their blood on a device that decomposes DNA into chunks and recreate the particular individual's mind. Then by some clever predictor/estimator algorithms reenacts the history of the universe to guess what their decision might be at that particular point in timespace during voting.

Alternative answer :

Not much really, people see the question and vote for closing via 5 different reasons; `Too Localized`, `Duplicate`, `Not a Real Question`, `Off Topic`, `Not Constructive`

It might happen that somehow the closing votes cast too quickly without carefully checking and/or the question is edited substantially making it a valid question. Then the question can be reopened. To avoid the immediate deletion and to encourage an edit on the question, you can't delete your question right away. This is probably to give you some time to reformulate your question. I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: I would say that generally it is a good idea to have a spare time between closure and deletion, so that not only the OP can think about re-formulating more than about deletion, but more high-rep users and mods see it and can disagree with the closure.

Comment: @tohecz: There might even though be particular cases in which that would not make any sense. But I admit that this procedure is in general the most reasonable!